# Simple If Else statement in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement

I'm trying to get only the rows that are in USD and EUR from a table with more currencies.

I thought the code should be something like:

```
SELECT IF(CONTRACTS_IN_DIFFERENT_CURRENCIES.CURRENCY='USD',1,0) OR IF(CONTRACTS_IN_DIFFERENT_CURRENCIES.CURRENCY='EUR',1,0
FROM CONTRACTS_IN_DIFFERENT_CURRENCIES
```

But I know this is not how it should be. I would like the table to be something like a column of USD and EUR

Comment: you need a WHERE clause

Comment: As crowne writes, you need to use a WHERE clause. Maybe you could give us an example on the table structure so we know what it looks like?

Comment: You need to add more brief regarding your question,as of now it is unclear and you will get wrong answers too until you explain it completely

Comment: Are you looking for a count of the number of contracts for each of those currencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preceding answers are good in my opinion, but let's say you would have alot of currencies, you could do

```
SELECT * FROM CONTRACTS_IN_DIFFERENT_CURRENCIES WHERE CURRENCY IN  ("USD","EUR")
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though you're trying to use Excel's `IF(condition, true_response, false_response)` syntax. The equivalent in T-SQL is the `CASE WHEN THEN ELSE END` syntax:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN CONTRACTS_IN_DIFFERENT_CURRENCIES.CURRENCY ='USD' THEN 1 
        WHEN CONTRACTS_IN_DIFFERENT_CURRENCIES.CURRENCY='EUR' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END 
FROM 
    CONTRACTS_IN_DIFFERENT_CURRENCIES
```

This will work with more complex queries than the example you're giving us. Another way of doing it, if you have a number of possible values for the same field that will return the same response, would be

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN CONTRACTS_IN_DIFFERENT_CURRENCIES.CURRENCY IN ('USD','EUR') THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END 
FROM 
    CONTRACTS_IN_DIFFERENT_CURRENCIES
```

However, that is not the right syntax to use to get just the rows with certain currencies; the previous answer with

```
SELECT *     
FROM 
    CONTRACTS_IN_DIFFERENT_CURRENCIES
WHERE 
    CONTRACTS_IN_DIFFERENT_CURRENCIES.CURRENCY IN ('USD','EUR')
```

would work best for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM CONTRACTS_IN_DIFFERENT_CURRENCIES WHERE
CONTRACTS_IN_DIFFERENT_CURRENCIES.CURRENCY='USD' OR CONTRACTS_IN_DIFFERENT_CURRENCIES.CURRENCY='EUR'
```

OR

```
SELECT * 
FROM CONTRACTS_IN_DIFFERENT_CURRENCIES WHERE
`CONTRACTS_IN_DIFFERENT_CURRENCIES`.`CURRENCY`="USD" OR `CONTRACTS_IN_DIFFERENT_CURRENCIES`.`CURRENCY`="EUR"
```

I have not understand `,1,0)` that part. So if you need some more condition use `AND`, `OR` and combination of brackets to achieve result.

Just to let you know, if you need disctinc (non repeating values) you can use word `DISTINCT` and state what fields exactly you need.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a WHERE clause.

As far as I can tell you're looking for a query along the lines of

```
SELECT * FROM `CONTRACTS_IN_DIFFERENT_CURRENCIES` WHERE `CURRENCY` = "USD" OR `CURRENCY` = "EUR"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the count of the number of contracts in each of those currencies with each count as a column (which seems to be indicated by one of the comments in your question), then use this…

```
SELECT SUM(CURRENCY = 'USD') AS usdContracts, 
    SUM(CURRENCY = 'EUR') AS eurContracts
FROM CONTRACTS_IN_DIFFERENT_CURRENCIES
```

If you want the count of the number of contracts in each of those currencies with each count as a row with the count in one column and the currency abbreviation in another, then use this…

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS numContracts, CURRENCY AS currency
FROM CONTRACTS_IN_DIFFERENT_CURRENCIES
WHERE CURRENCY = 'USD' OR CURRENCY = 'EUR'
GROUP BY CURRENCY;
```