# Multiplying column if statement is true

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement

I have a column of USD and EUR currencies and would like to multiply the values to the corresponding exchange in chilean pesos. So far I know how to extract the contracts that are in USDand the ones that are in EUR but I don't kow how to multiply each value by its own exchange rate. I think it could be something like:

```
SELECT contracts.value, contracts.currency 
FROM contracts
WHERE contracts.currency='USD' then contracts.value=contracts.value*500  
   OR contracts.currency='EUR' then contracts.value=contracts.value*750
```

Thank you agian for the help!

Comment: The answers below are valid, but I'd suggest, if possible, not doing this and instead making an exchange rate table and doing a join. Easier to update a database than code.

Comment: Given your [earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23616470/simple-if-else-statement-in-sql) and this one, I would really suggest you do some basic SQL learning before embarking on something like this so that you are not posting a new question for every step along the way. This site is not a guided tutorial.

Comment: I may not know as much as you but I think these are valid questions, I'm sorry to bother you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter your `contracts.value` by `contracts.currency` using `CASE` statement :

```
 SELECT contracts.currency 
      , CASE WHEN contracts.currency = 'USD' THEN contracts.value*500 
             WHEN contracts.currency = 'EUR' THEN contracts.value*750
             ELSE contracts.value
        END
 FROM contracts
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do that in the select clause:

```
SELECT IF(contracts.currency='USD', contracts.value*500, contracts.value*750) as amount
FROM contracts
```

Documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html

Comment: There are more than 2 currencies, what would I do then?

Comment: If there are more than two, use a CASE statement like Notulysses's answer

Answer (score 1):

If your going to have more than two currencies, you could use a lookup table.

```
currency | factor
-----------------
USD      | 500
EUR      | 750
```

ANd then query like this:

```
SELECT c.contract_id, c.contract, c.value, c.currency, 
    cc.factor, c.value * cc.factor    AS calculatedValue
FROM contract c
    INNER JOIN currency_conversion cc ON c.currency = cc.currency
```

Demo here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3797e/2